# Conditionally Populate GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp:GridView tied to an asp:SqlDataSource that gets populated after the user clicks a button in the UI.

For security, I do not want the GridView to populate unless some business logic checks succeed first.

What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: In your button clicked handler, put the code to populate the gridview in an if statement.

Comment: @Hans Z I do the check in Page_Load, and redirect to an error page if it fails... but for some reason it doesnt take the redirect if I resend the captured http request postback from something like Fiddler. Why would this be (in debugging I can see it hits the redirect line of code, but then does nothing as it passes over it and continues on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way would be to do it on Code Behind. Don't set the DataSource in the mark up and just assign the `Datasource` on code behind after you have executed your business logic and verify that it should populate the grid:

```
protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(validateBusinessRules())
    {
        gridview1.DataSource=SqlDataSource2;
        gridview1.DataBind();
    }
}
```